# Drawing elements in drawRect on top of a CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I am trying to create a ring that animates a fill of a lighter color around it. I plan to draw the circle in drawRect and animate the fill in a CAShapeLayer and draw a white circle on top. So far my circle looks like this in the simulator:

[image]

I need the lighter color around the edges only. Is it possible to place the CAShapeLayer between the two circles drawn in drawRect? Code below:

```
class MyTimer: UIView {

    let circleBgColor: UIColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 244.0/255.0, green: 165.0/255.0, blue: 35.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    let circleFgColor : UIColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 254.0/255.0, green: 198.0/255.0, blue: 106.0/255.0, alpha: 1)

    let timeLeftLayer = CAShapeLayer()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.config()
    }

    //Only called in IB
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.config()
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    }

    //Common code here
    func config() {

        backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        //initially full of time left
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2.0, y: frame.size.height / 2.0), radius: frame.size.width/2, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), clockwise: true)
        timeLeftLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath
        timeLeftLayer.fillColor = circleFgColor.CGColor
        timeLeftLayer.strokeEnd = 1

    }



    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let outterCirclePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
        circleBgColor.setFill()
        outterCirclePath.fill()


        layer.addSublayer(timeLeftLayer)


        let centerCirclePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.size.width/2, y: rect.size.height/2), radius: rect.size.height*0.4, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI*2), clockwise: true
        )

        UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
        centerCirclePath.fill()


    }

}
```

any pointers on this would be great. thanks

Comment: You can draw everything on 'drawRect'. Add sublayer is in wrong place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placing a layer between two drawings is not possible because your drawings are painted in the same layer, more specifically in view's main layer. What you should do is separating each drawing on a single layer and then placing a layer between two layers is totally possible.

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    // backLayer drawing 
    let backLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    backLayer.frame = self.bounds
    backLayer.fillColor = circleBgColor.CGColor
    backLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect).CGPath
    self.layer.addSublayer(backLayer)

    // middleLayer drawing
    self.layer.addSublayer(timeLeftLayer)

    // frontLayer drawing
    let frontLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    frontLayer.frame = self.bounds
    frontLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    frontLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.size.width/2, y: rect.size.height/2), radius: rect.size.height*0.4, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI*2), clockwise: true
    ).CGPath
    self.layer.addSublayer(frontLayer)
}
```